# Is WebView2 supported in the Citrix Server

Tags: citrix, webview2

We have an application from third party, it requires WebView2. Installed WebView2 in our machine as per instruction, it is working fine in our desktop.
We installed exactly in the same way in the Citrix server, but it is not working. Any idea if the Citrix Server supports WebView2 or any specific action needed. The third Party does not provide customer support for the Citrix installation - Please help.

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar issue with WebView2. It worked just fine everywhere, except on our Citrix environment.
The solution that made it work for "msedgewebview2.exe" is described here: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX107825

REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Citrix\CtxHook /v ExcludedImageNames /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d msedgewebview2.exe /f

REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Citrix\CtxHook /v ExcludedImageNames /t

REG_EXPAND_SZ /d msedgewebview2.exe /f

REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Citrix\CtxHook64 /v ExcludedImageNames /t

REG_EXPAND_SZ /d msedgewebview2.exe /f