# Microsoft edge webView2 causes performance issue on citrix server

Tags: microsoft-edge, outlook-web-addins, citrix, webview2

We have noticed that there is issue on the Citrix environment in regards to WebView2. We are trying to run office add-in inside the Outlook desktop (365) and as soon as Outlook tries to run the add-in we can see in the task manager that CPU and Memory usage spikes from 8 percent to 99 percent. Multiple instance of WebView2 processes running can be seen which consumes most of the processing power. The office add-in is not able to load at all. We have tried 2-3 office add-ins and we see the same behavior. There is no Microsoft edge installed on the Citrix .

Version
Runtime: 90.0.818.56
OS: win 10

Screenshots
[Task Manager usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulMyN.png)

Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114188/is-webview2-supported-in-the-citrix-server

Comment: Hi @YuZhou, I am sorry, I was not able to test it out on the citrix yet due to our capacity. I will do it soon and let you know. Thank you so much for your feedback.

Comment: @PoulBak Thank you the information. That really helped me to solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be caused by hooks in Citrix which preventing the WebView2 component from starting. It can be fixed by adding the WebView2 process as an exception from all Citrix hooks. You can refer to [this article](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX107825) to edit the registry to achieve this.

Reference link:

[Webview2 application running in a Citrix environment](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1082)

[Is WebView2 supported in the Citrix Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114188/is-webview2-supported-in-the-citrix-server)

Comment: The second link worked for me. Thanks so much again.